# VB.Net ShowDialog how to close

Tags: vb.net

Hello i have a code here that shows a loading dialog and i cant seem to close it
can anyone please help me

```
        'Show Loading
        Dim MLUI As New MiniLoadingUI()
        MLUI.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: MLUI.Close() - maybe instead show the context of where this is being used...you should also be disposing of the form

Comment: Where are you trying to close it?  ShowDialog blocks any code under it until the form is closed.

Comment: Thanks @LarsTech Problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it is worth, you should be wrapping your declaration in Using statements:

```
Using MLUI As New MiniLoadingUI()
   MLUI.ShowDialog()
End Using
```

As far as your problem goes, you should simply call the following:

```
MLUI.Close()
```

However it is worth noting that ShowDialog shows the form as a modal dialog box which means that unless you would be calling the Close method in a timer, it would need to be closed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

you can try Dispose() or close() for close form.

```
Dim MLUI As New MiniLoadingUI()
MLUI.ShowDialog()
MLUI.dispose()
```